# Require.js How to take shim config into account with plugins

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm building a require.js loader plugins and I have trouble when using my plugins with a module using a shim config.

My plugins load the right path, but it won't rely on any of the `shim` setting like `deps` or `exports`.

Does the plugin need to take care of parsing the shim config, or is there a special function  to be sure require.js parse the shim ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been able to resolve my issue.

You need to make sure to require the `module name` (and not the path), and make sure you return this require call return value in the `onLoad` callback

Like so

```
req(toLoad, function ( value ) {
    onLoad( value );
});
```